Evitar herencia de estilos en react bootstrap
estoy haciendo una aplicacion de tareas, algo simple con React. Agregue React bootstrap para generar los estilos mas rapido, pero ahora que estoy aplicando condiciones de estilos para las tareas, no me aplica los estilos que genere desde mi archivo de sass. Aunque en el archivo sass a los estilos les aplique !important, no los toma. Incluso intente cambiando el orden de los archivos pero sigo con el problema. Inspeccionando en Chrome, me pude percatar que hay unos estilos que se heredan, ¿como podria evitar eso?
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Task } from '../../models/task.class'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { LEVELS } from '../../models/levels.enum'
//Importar hoja de estilos task.scss
import '../../styles/task.scss'

import { Badge } from 'react-bootstrap'

const TaskComponent = ({ task, complete, remove }) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Created task');
        return () => {
            console.log(`Task: ${ task.name } is going to unmount...`);
        }
    }, [ task ]);

    //Function that returns a Badge depending on the level of the task
    function taskLevelBadge() {
        switch (task.level) {
            case LEVELS.NORMAL:
                return( <h6 className='mb-0'>
                    {/* <span>
                        { task.level }
                    </span> */}
                    <Badge className='bg-primary'>
                        { task.level }
                    </Badge>
                </h6> )
            case LEVELS.URGENT:
                return( <h6 className='mb-0'>
                    <Badge className='bg-warning'>
                        { task.level }
                    </Badge>
                </h6> )
            case LEVELS.BLOCKING:
                return( <h6 className='mb-0'>
                    <Badge className='bg-danger'>
                        { task.level }
                    </Badge>
                </h6> )
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    //Function that returns icon depending if task is completed or not
    function taskCompĺetedIcon() {
        if( task.completed ){
            return( <i onClick={ () => complete(task) } className='bi-toggle-on task-action' style={ { color:'green', fontWeight: 'bold' } }></i> )
        }else{
            return( <i onClick={ () => complete(task) } className='bi-toggle-off task-action' style={ {color:'gray', fontWeight: 'bold' } }></i> )
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <tr className={ task.completed ? 'task-completed' :  'task-pending' }>  {/* Esta es la condicion que no se aplica. */}
                <th>
                    <span className='ms-2'>{ task.name }</span>
                </th>
                <td className='align-middle'>
                    <span>{ task.description }</span>
                </td>
                <td className='align-middle'>
                    {/* Execution of function to return badge element */}
                    { taskLevelBadge() } 
                </td>
                {/* TODO: Sustituir por iconos */}
                <td className='align-middle'>
                    {/* Execution of function to return icon depending on completion */}
                    { taskCompĺetedIcon() }
                    {/* <span>{ task.completed ? 'Completed' : 'Pending' }</span> */}
                    <i className='bi-trash task-action' style={ { color: 'tomato', fontSize: '20px' } } onClick={ () => remove(task) }></i>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </>
    );
}

TaskComponent.propTypes = {
    task: PropTypes.instanceOf( Task ),
    complete: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    remove: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default TaskComponent



Y si agregas la etiqueta 
tal vez quieras revisar react styled components

@RobertoMoralesFumero ya intente con la etiqueta style, pero sigue el mismo problema. Aplique la condicional con en la etiqueta style.

@RuslanLópez ok, parece que si checare eso.

@RobertoMoralesFumero la unica solucion que vi es en el archivo sass, agregarle estilos al hijo, en este caso, es un span.
